# Running Async tasks run in series

Tags: swift

I have an array of html page links and I want to load such links one by one.

I am using HTMLKit.

Obviously downloading an HTML page is an async operation.

I am using something like

```
func getPage(_ url:Url) {
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.innerHTML") {result, error in {
      // get page
    } 
}
```

That is an async operation.

And this is called from something like

```
for link in links {
    getPage(link)
}
```

Because this loop runs fast as hell, the async operation has no time to run and just the last link is downloaded.

How can I do the loop wait for one page to be finished before proceeding to the next?

Comment: `evaluateJavaScript` is `async throws`. `try await webView.evaluateJavaScript(...)`, and make `getPage` `async throws` too. Then you can do `try await getPage()` in the loop.

Comment: Brilliant. Please make this comment an answer.

Comment: I disagree with your assessment that only the last URL is downloaded and that because it's "fast as hell" (how JS is fast as hell is another question, though :D ).  What you do here is calling a completion-handler-style-async function in a loop where each call returns immediately after you initiated the underlying async task. Per definition and per convention, an async function with a completion handler MUST eventually call the provided closure, and only once. What then should have happened is represented in our comment "get page", actually you "got" the result or an error, links.count time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your `getPage` function `async` with the help of `Continuation` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/checkedcontinuation)

```swift
    func getPage(_ url: URL) -> async throws ReturnType {
        return try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
            webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.innerHTML") { result, error in
                if let error {
                    continuation.resume(throwing: error)
                }
                
                if result == .success(let data) {
                    continuation.resume(returning: data)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```swift
for link in links {
   do {
      try await getPage(link)
   } catch {
     // Handle error
   }
}
```

Note: As your code is not buildable the solution of the code is conceptual here. You can take some code example in this link in `Continuation` section https://github.com/MahiAlJawad/ModernSwiftConcurrency-iOS

Comment: [`evaluateJavaScript(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1415017-evaluatejavascript) has already an `async` counterpart

Comment: Yes but it is closure based. So you need to wrap inside continuation.

Comment: Another solution would be: serialize inside a SerialQueue. It is an older approach.

Comment: If ‘evaluateJavaScript(:)’ was marked async it wasn’t possible to call without await.  It seems from the question that is it ans asynchronous function but send result with closure. That requires Continuation.

Comment: thanks for all comments and for the answer.

Comment: *Yes but it is closure based*. No, it's not, there is an `func evaluateJavaScript(_ javaScriptString: String) async throws -> Any` API, no closure. Please have a look at the documentation.

Comment: Got your point. My answer was based on the closure based version.

Answer (score 2):

`evaluateJavaScript(_:completionHandler:)` has an `async` counterpart which is

```
func evaluateJavaScript(_ javaScriptString: String) async throws -> Any
```

So just rewrite `getPage` and make it `async throws`

```
func getPage(_ url: URL) async throws {
    let page = try await webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.innerHTML")
    // do something with page
}
```

and to use it

```
let links = [URL]()
Task {
    do {
        for link in links {
            try await getPage(link)
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

The links are processed sequentially one after another.